# finding a minimum amount according to an array of struct through comparison or other means in c programming

Tags: c, arrays, struct, comparison

I am trying to find a way to find the minimum amount of lane to go through. For this program, I must go through all the class in the struct in the according direction as shown in the diagram in the following link:

[Direction instruction diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TErm3.png)

In the program provided as example:

I must go through **a, b, d and e** lane. However, based on the direction, the minimum amount of lane needs to go through is **6**. As I need to goes down before goes up on d and I need to goes back up after e.

```js
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_CLASSES 4

typedef struct{
 char alpha;
}class_t;

int
main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
 int i, n=MAX_CLASSES;
 class_t classes[MAX_CLASSES] = {
  [0]={.alpha = 'a'},
  [1]={.alpha = 'b'},
  [2]={.alpha = 'd'},
  [3]={.alpha = 'e'},
 };
 
 printf("the letters are:");
 for (i=0; i<n; i++){
  printf(" %c", classes[i].alpha);
 }
 printf("\n");
 
 printf("minimum lane is.....?");
  

 
 return 0;
}
```

---

Another example, if I got b and c. Then I must go down first to go up at b and after goes down at c, I need to go back up after so the minimum amount of lane is 4.

And another example, if I got a and b then the minimum amount of lane is 2 as I can just go down at a and goes back up at b.

Something about the alphabet in the struct:

- There will not be redundant alphabet
- They are in ascending order
- They can be in any length (n could be any positive integer)

Any idea how can I calculate the minimum amount of lane in c? Should I use comparison if so how?

This is what I have so far:

```js
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_CLASSES 3

typedef struct{
 char alpha;
}class_t;

int
main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
 int i, j, lane, n=MAX_CLASSES;
 class_t classes[MAX_CLASSES] = {
  [0]={.alpha = 'a'},
  [1]={.alpha = 'b'},
  [2]={.alpha = 'c'},
 };
 
 printf("the letters are:");
 for (i=0; i<n; i++){
  printf(" %c", classes[i].alpha);
 }
 printf("\n");
 
 if(n==1){
  lane = 2;
 }
 
 if(n>1){
  lane = 0;
  for(i=0; i<j; i++){
   for(j=i+1; j<n; j++){
    if(classes[i].alpha%2==1){
     if(classes[j].alpha%2==1){
      lane += 4;
     }else{
      lane += 2;
     }
    }else{
     lane = 1;
     if(classes[j].alpha%2==1){
      lane += 4;
     }else{
      lane += 2;
     }
    }
   }
  }
 }
 if(classes[n-1].alpha%2==1){
  lane +=1;
 }
 
 printf("minimum lane is %d", lane);
  

 
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: the posted code does not cleanly compile! when the parameters to the `main()` function are not used, then use the signature: `int main( void )`

Comment: the posted code contains some 'magic' numbers.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis. I.E. 4.  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  Suggest using a `#define` statement or a `enum` statement to give 'magic' numbers meaningful names, then use those meaningful names throughout the code.

Comment: it is a poor programming practice to `#include` header files those contents are not used in the code.

Comment: what do you mean a time component? there isnt any thing involve time??

Comment: your right, I misread the question.  Here is what I meant to say: "There is no `lane` component in your question , so this statement: `Any idea how can I calculate the minimum amount of lane in c? Should I use comparison if so how?` has no meaning"

Comment: my question was to how can i calculate that number, i edited that out, hopefully it makes more sense

Comment: lane should calculate by the alphabet as odd ASCII alphabet is downward lane and even is upward lane. I.e. me as a person must travel downward then upward for each lane but if there are a and b, it will have the same lane number as a.  my problem is i dont know how can I translate that into c

Comment: suggest writing (in text, in the question) the actual steps you want to perform to traverse a lane and to traverse the whole maze.

Answer (score 0):

here is a proposed version of the code that:

1. cleanly compiles
2. does not contain 'magic' numbers
3. properly calculates the value for the variable `n`

and now the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct lanes
{
    char alpha;
};
typedef struct lanes class_t;


int main( void )
{
    int min_lane = 6;

    class_t classes[] =
    {
        [0]={.alpha = 'a'},
        [1]={.alpha = 'b'},
        [2]={.alpha = 'd'},
        [3]={.alpha = 'e'},
    };

    int n = sizeof( classes ) / sizeof( class_t );

    printf("the letters are:");

    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        printf(" %c", classes[i].alpha);
    }

    printf("\n");

    printf("minimum lane is %d", min_lane);

    return 0;
}
```

However, the code is meaningless as there is no concept of `lane`, nor a clear definition of how a `lane` is to be traversed.

Please re-word the question to indicate what your trying to accomplish.

Comment: the goal of the code is to find min of lane, I added a number in but my goal was to calculate that number based on the alphabet.... so not sure what do you mean by time?

Comment: ie i have 4 alphabet and based on that i will have 6 minimum lane based on calculation, the problem is i dont know how to translate that calculation into c

Comment: per the linked diagram, enter, turn left, forward until end, turn left exit.  None of the data structures, posted by OP, has any concept of the a...g of any lane,   Please explain what you mean by traversing a lane and why exactly 6 lanes